# Change measuring point of forces and moments

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, torque

I have a question regarding how to express forces and moments with respect to a different point.
Assume I have a measuring point $A$ where I obtain forces $F_x$ $F_y$ $F_z$ and Moments $M_x$ $M_y$ $M_z$ acting on that point $A$.
Assume we have a point $B$ which is connected to point $A$ via a rigid body with known dimensions. I don't want to transform the forces and moments to another coordinate frame, but "measure" the forces *at* point $B$.
Is it actually possible to derive forces and moments  $F_x'$ $F_y'$ $F_z'$ $M_x'$ $M_y'$ $M_z'$ acting on point $B$ through the given forces and dimensions of the rigid body?

EDIT:
I especially would like to know if given a Moment at Point $A$, what is the way to derive forces (and moments) at point $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moments tell you where a force is applied. The force vector will give you the magnitude and direction of a force, but not *where* the line of action of the force is.

This is why measuring forces at different points always produces the same result, but the resulting moments change with location.

To get the line of action you need the moments.

If at point *A* (with location $\vec{r}_A$) you measure forces and moments $$\begin{aligned} \vec{F} & = \pmatrix{F_x \\ F_y \\ F_z} & \vec{M}_A & = \pmatrix{M_x \\ M_y \\ M_z} \end{aligned} $$

then the line of action is located at

$$ \vec{r}_{\rm action} = \vec{r}_A + \frac{ \vec{F} \times \vec{M}_A } { \| \vec{F} \|^2} \tag{1}$$

If you were to measure the forces and moments at a different point *B* (located at $\vec{r}_B$) you would find that the line of action is at

$$ \vec{r}_{\rm action} = \vec{r}_B + \frac{ \vec{F} \times \vec{M}_B } { \| \vec{F} \|^2} \tag{2}$$

Both produce the same location. Well almost, each location is the point on the line of action closest to the measuring point. Their difference is always parallel to $\vec{F}$.

You can prove (1) this since moments transfer with the usual law $\vec{M}_B = \vec{M}_A + (\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_B) \times \vec{F} $

Use (1) but transfer the force from $\vec{r}_A$ to $\vec{r}_{\rm action}$

$$ \begin{aligned}\vec{M}_{{\rm action}} & =\vec{M}_{A}+\left(\vec{r}_{A}-\vec{r}_{{\rm action}}\right)\times\vec{F}\\
 & =\vec{M}_{A}+\left(\vec{r}_{A}-\vec{r}_{A}-\frac{\vec{F}\times\vec{M}_{A}}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\right)\times\vec{F}\\
 & =\vec{M}_{A}-\frac{\left(\vec{F}\times\vec{M}_{A}\right)\times\vec{F}}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\\
 & =\vec{M}_{A}-\frac{\vec{M}_{A}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{F}\right)-\vec{F}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{M_{A}}\right)}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\\
 & =\frac{\vec{F}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{M_{A}}\right)}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}
\end{aligned} $$

This means that the moment along the line of action is strictly parallel to the force vector $\vec F$ by a scalar factor $$h = \frac{\vec{F}\cdot \vec{M}_A}{\|\vec{F}\|^2} \tag{3}$$

This factor in $\vec{M}_{\rm action} = h \, \vec{F}$ is called the pitch.

You can reconstruct $\vec{M}_A$ from the line of action location $\vec{r}_{\rm action}$ and the pitch $h$ by the following process

$$\begin{aligned}\vec{M}_{A} & =h\vec{F}+\left(\vec{r}_{{\rm action}}-\vec{r}_{A}\right)\times\vec{F}\\
 & =\left(\frac{\vec{F}\cdot\vec{M_{A}}}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\right)\vec{F}+\left(\frac{\vec{F}\times\vec{M}_{A}}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\right)\times\vec{F}\\
 & =\frac{\vec{F}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{M_{A}}\right)}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}+\frac{\vec{F}\times\left(\vec{M}_{A}\times\vec{F}\right)}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\\
 & =\frac{\vec{F}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{M_{A}}\right)+\vec{M}_{A}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{F}\right)-\vec{F}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{M}_{A}\right)}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}\\
 & =\frac{\vec{M}_{A}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{F}\right)}{\|\vec{F}\|^{2}}=\vec{M_{A}}\;\checkmark
\end{aligned}$$